# Нужна помощь с селекторами CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопрос на картинке, ответил как на картинке - не верно
Тест с сайта mail.ru для получения сертификата CSS

Первый вариант - обычная группировка. Два тега, через запятую
Второй вариант - тег h4 с классом .p
Третий вариант - тег p с идентификатором #h4
Четвертый вариант - Вовсе нерабочий (проверял)
Пятый вариант - тег h4 с идентификатором #p и класcом ext

Если я все пункты верно интерпретировал, то получается, что селекторы с использованием класса - только два, как раз те, что я отметил.

Кстати, Sublime четко выделяет цветом. После решетки - id, после точки - class

Где истина?

Comment: Ошибка в тесте? Этот вопрос хорошо бы задать тем, кто отвечает за этот тест. Обратитесь к ним по обратной связи, если она у них есть конечно, может ответят что-то.

Comment: Скорее всего это не ошибка, а вопрос с подвохом, ибо мы не знаем наверняка является ли `p` классом. Если учитывать что `p, h4` - это элементы, а `.ext` класс, то в данном тесте верный ответ - `h4#p.ext`, хоть и не рабочий ответ)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, точка в селекторах однозначно указывает на класс и что надо найти класс, по другому быть не может. Если же надо найти элемент, то указывается без точки, но наличии одноименного класса `.p { ... }` и элемента `p { ... }` вполне законно. Вариант `h4#p.ext` тоже рабочий, он просто требует наличия и id и class одновременно.

Comment: @AlexKrass, нам не известно, что в итоге в HTML, если глянуть на первый ответ, то видно что `p` и `h4` всё таки элементы, следовательно из классов существует только `.ext`, из чего следует вывод, что запись `h4#p,exp` не сработает из-за отсутствие элемента `<h4 id="p" class="ext">`

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, понял. Не, как правило это общетеоретические вопросы, они не привязаны к конкретному HTML. В них просто требуется определить, на что натравливается селектор без какого-либо HTML. Связей между вариантами нет. Поэтому как правило ответ в тупую - видим точку и валидный селектор, отмечаем как правильный.